# Backtesting my strategy on another indicator

Tags: pine-script

I can't seem to backtest my custom strategy which is applied to the Stoch RSI indicator. The result I get is: "To test a strategy, apply it to the chart" (i.e., nothing is executed). So if it's applied to a study, it won't work? How do I then create a strategy that is applied to the chart, yet references the Stoch RSI study?

```
//@version=3
strategy("Stoch RSI Strategy", overlay=true)

// Links
k = input(title="K Source", type=source, defval=close)
d = input(title="D Source", type=source, defval=close)

// Strategy
pivoting = k > 80 or k < 20
bullish = k > d and pivoting
bearish = k < d and pivoting

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=bullish)
strategy.entry("Stop", strategy.short, when=bearish)
```

EDIT: It seems buggy too...I'm now getting the error: "This indicator cannot be applied to another indicator".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tv can't strategy on study or multiple source inputs :( But there is workaround:

```
//@version=3
strategy("Stoch RSI Strategy", overlay=true)
smoothK = input(3, minval=1)
smoothD = input(3, minval=1)
lengthRSI = input(14, minval=1)
lengthStoch = input(14, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")

rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)

// Strategy
pivoting = k > 80 or k < 20
bullish = k > d and pivoting
bearish = k < d and pivoting

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=bullish)
strategy.entry("Stop", strategy.short, when=bearish)
```